# boost::shared_ptr question. Why does this work?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, shared-ptr

In experimenting with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4389650/348056) I created an example that I utterly do not understand.  In particular, it highlights my misunderstanding of pointers, references, and the boost::shared_ptr.

```
int& r = *(new int(0));//gratuitous pointer leak, got to initialize it to something
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(100));
    r = *sp;
    cout << "r=" << r << endl;
}
cout << "r=" << r << endl << endl;

int* p;
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(100));
    p = &*sp;
    cout << "*p=" << *p << endl;
}
cout << "*p=" << *p << endl;
```

Running this code gives an output something like this:

```
r=100
r=100

*p=100
*p=13
```

Why does the reference survive the death of the shared_ptr but the pointer does not?

---

There's a problem in the answers here in that there seem to be two diametrically opposed and contradictory solutions and no consensus upon which is the truth.  I would like the ability to use a reference after a shared_ptr is deleted, but if it's invalid I really need to understand this.

Perhaps someone can post a simple example that demonstrates the undefined behavior in the reference.

Comment: If I reverse the order of the blocks then still the reference survives, and the pointer does not.  However you're saying that this is merely luck, right?

Comment: my comment was wrong, see @FredOverflow's answer.  Sorry...

Comment: Please don't write `*(new ...)`. You're saying, in effect, "please allocate some memory from the heap, and then forget that the memory came from the heap". If you then assign to a value rather than a reference, you have an unrecoverable memory leak. Even assigning to the reference, cleaning up requires `delete &r`, which is horribly un-idiomatic.

Comment: @Karl, I don't think this matters when you are intentionally pointing out subtle differences between pointers and references.  In production code a function like this would not exist in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `r = *sp;` does not do what you think it does. It assigns to **the referent**, that is, to the anonymous `int` object you created on the heap in line 1. You cannot reseat references in C++.

Here is what the standard says about evaluating reference expressions:

> If an expression initially has the type "reference to `T`",
>   the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.
>   **The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference**,
>   and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

So you see, there is no way to get to "the reference itself". It simply does not exist in C++.

Maybe this code will make it clearer:

```
int a = 42;
int b = 97;

int&r = a;   // r is just an alias (another name) for a
    r = b;   // assigns b to a (does NOT bind r to b, that's impossible in C++!)
```

After executing the last line, both `a` and `b` contain 97, because `r = b` really means `a = b`.

Comment: so it's as if I'm coding something like this?: `(&r)=(&*sp);`

Comment: No; it's as if you're coding... hold your breath... `r = *sp`. `r` is best thought of as a newly-assigned name for an already-existing value. You're reading the value pointed at by the shared pointer, and assigning it to the chunk of memory that `r` refers to. You are not causing `r` to refer to a different chunk of memory; that is impossible. `r` is a new name for **a value**. Values don't move (at least, not pre-0x).

Comment: @FredOverflow So then you're indicating that in my example it's ok to use the reference after the corresponding shared_ptr is deleted.  I don't understand how a reference that references a deleted value can have defined behavior... although in my current case it would be helpful if it did.

Comment: @John: But the reference does not correspond to the `shared_ptr` **at all**! First, you create an anonymous object on the heap with the value 0. Let's just call that `a`. Then you create a different anonymous object on the heap with the value 100. Let's call that `b`. Then you give the responsibility of deleting `b` to a `shared_ptr` called `sp`. Then you assign **the value** of `b` to `a`. **The reference `r` is still bound to `a` at this point. It still has no connection whatsoever with `b`.** Then `sp` falls out of scope an deletes `b`, but `a` is not affected by this, and neither is `r`.

Comment: @FredOverflow ok, I think I get it now, so correct me if I'm still wrong.  When I create a reference `r`, it is forever and always and irrevocably bound to (i.e. an alias of) the value at a certain address.  You called this value `a`.  When I have a statement such as `r = b` then what this really says is that `a` (and it's alias `r`) is now a copy of `b` (but not `b` itself).  Thus whenever I delete `b`, `a` (and it's alias `r`) are unaffected.  Sound right?

Comment: @John: Yes, that sounds right. Although I wouldn't say that `r` is bound to a *value*, but rather to an *object*, but now we're splitting hairs :)

Comment: @FredOverflow Ok, you're really going to hate me for this, but since I feel like you have a lot to teach me, would you care look at my new question that delves even deeper into my misunderstanding? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4390945/348056

Answer (score 2):

p is undefined, r is a copy

```
int& r = *(new int(0));
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(100));
    r = *sp; // copy
    cout << "r=" << r << endl;
}
cout << "r=" << r << endl << endl;

int* p;
{
    boost::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(100));
    p = &*sp;
    cout << "*p=" << *p << endl;
}
cout << "*p=" << *p << endl; // Undefined, pointer points to deleted int
```

Comment: @ronag: the value where the pointer points to was copied to where the reference points.

Comment: It is referring (not pointing; it isn't a pointer) to **the int that was allocated by** `new int(0)`. That int gets overwritten with 100. It works the same as if we had initialized the reference with a literal value e.g. `int& r = 0;`, which in turn works the same as if we had used a value instead of a reference e.g. `int r = 0;`. A reference simply associates an(other) name with a value. It should not be thought of as some kind of magical pseudo-pointer, because by the time you've added enough explanation of how it differs from a pointer, you really don't understand what is going on any more.

Comment: @Karl: `int& r = 0` does not compile though, because you cannot bind lvalue references to rvalues ;)

Comment: @Fred true, but you know what I meant ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, your `int`-object is destructed. In the first case it is not.

In the first case, you create a new `int`-object with `new` in the outer scope. In the inner scope, you create a second `int`-object, for which you also create a `shared_ptr`, which then owns the `int`-object. This `shared_ptr` runs out of scope when you close the inner scope, it therefore gets destructed. The `shared_ptr` destructor will also destruct the object it refers to, because no other `shared_ptr` (that was created from the original one) refers to your `int` object anymore. That's all alright. However, in the middle of that scope you re-assign the value of `r` to that of `*sp` (100). You therefore save the value of `*sp`, before `sp` gets destructed, into `r`.

Note: it's certainly questionable style to create an `int` object the way you do it in your first line of code. If you don't explicitly delete that `int` object, this is a memory leek. The way to destruct it would be `delete &r` which looks really ugly, especially because the symbol `r` afterwards still refers to the, now deleted, `int` object. DON'T DO THIS!

In the second case you create an `int` pointer at the beginning, but no `int` object. The inner scope is almost the same as before, except that this time you do not save the value of your new `int` object into the outer-scope variable (`p`), but you save the address of the `int` object! As the `int` object gets destructed at the end of the inner scope (for the same reason as previously), `p` no longer points to an existing `int` object, but to a place in memory which formerly once hold an `int` object. The value you get from `*p` is undefined: you might still get 100, you could get any other value, and you might even crash your programme here (Segmentation fault) as you dereference a memory location you no longer hold.

So to summarise, and answer your final question:

The reference survives, because it still refers to an existing object. The pointer does not, because it points to a no longer existing object.